# Different IP location from origin ISP

Tags: networking, router, isp, ipv4

So, I'm from **India** recently my ISP **Excitel** located in India modify their network. I think it's merge to **cogent** ISP which located in **United State** which completely provide different external IP, if I search *whatsmyip location* which give United State location without VPN.

Due to this IP location issue my WiFi network act like a VPN, and OTT platform block my subscription mean I can't stream on devices directly connected to WiFi network.

I tried VPN services to switch to Indian Ip to access OTT content, but the VPN app show ads and i don't like ads.

Comment: You should contact both your ISP and your IPTV (?) provider about this change.

Comment: i already contact ISP they saw senior are fixing the issue, but ISP take too much time to resolve it, i need temp solution

Comment: this question is too broad, however I tried to give you a few options in my answer

Comment: This type of issue usually shakes itself out over time. My ISP changed their subnet ranges a few years ago & for two weeks everything thought I lives 200 miles away. As it was still in the same country it wasn't too much of an issue. Eventually the world's caches got updated & I was back 'home'.

Comment: thanks for community help, today when i reboot my router this issue solve automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options here:

- get a friend of yours to install a VPN server you can use until the issue gets resolved e.g. [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/)
- search for a / use a free VPN services without ads, there are a few ones around, but I never search for one in India
- pay for a VPN and/or get reimbursed from your ISP
- ask your ISP if they can offer you a free VPN service
- ask a neighbour if you can use their WiFi